# Show that $trv=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\det(I+tv)-1}{t}$ for any n by n matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, limits

> Prove that for any n by n real matrix $v\in {\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$,  $trv=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\det(I+tv)-1}{t}$, where $t\in\mathbb R$, $I$ is the identity matirx, and $trv$ denotes the trace of the matrix $v$.

Let $v=r\in\mathbb R$, then $v$ is a one by one matrix, and $trv=r$, R.H.S$={\lim}_{t\to 0}\frac{1+tr-1}{t}={\lim}_{t\to 0}\frac{tr}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}r=r=$L.H.S

Let $v=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$, then $\det (I+tv)=(ta+1)(td+1)-bct^2$, so R.H.S=$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(ta+1)(td+1)-bct^2-1}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{adt^2+(a+d)t+1-bct^2-1}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}adt+(a+d)-bct=a+d=trv=$L.H.S

I thought I should prove the claim by mathematical induction and expand the $k+1$th determinant in terms of the $kth$ matrix. But that's so cumbersome. Does anyone have a easier way to prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the identity that as $t\rightarrow 0$, (see Equation $4$, [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities/)) 
$$\det(I+tv)=1+t\cdot tr(v)+O(t^2)\sim1+t\cdot tr(v)$$
Thus we have
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\det(I+tv)-1}{t}\sim\frac{1+t\cdot tr(v)-1}{t}=tr(v)$$

The above identity is obtained using the derivative of the determinant and a Taylor expansion, where (from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Derivative))
$$\det(A+\epsilon X)-\det(A)=tr(adj(A)X)\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2)$$
Setting $A=I$, $B=v$ and $\epsilon = t$ results in
$$\det(I+tv)=\det(I)+t\cdot tr(v)+O(t^2)$$

Comment: How do you prove this identity then?

Comment: Please see edits to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}
   \varepsilon a_{1,1} + 1 &\varepsilon  a_{1,2} & \cdots & \varepsilon a_{1,n} \\
   \varepsilon a_{2,1} &\varepsilon  a_{2,2}+ 1  & \cdots & \varepsilon a_{2,n} \\
   \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
   \varepsilon a_{n,1} & \varepsilon a_{n,2} & \cdots & \varepsilon a_{n,n}+ 1  \end{pmatrix}
\\= 
\det\begin{pmatrix}
    1 &0& \cdots & 0 \\
   \varepsilon a_{2,1} &\varepsilon  a_{2,2}+ 1  & \cdots & \varepsilon a_{2,n} \\
   \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
   \varepsilon a_{n,1} & \varepsilon a_{n,2} & \cdots & \varepsilon a_{n,n}+ 1  \end{pmatrix}
+ \varepsilon \det\begin{pmatrix}
   a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\
   \varepsilon a_{2,1} &\varepsilon  a_{2,2}+ 1  & \cdots & \varepsilon a_{2,n} \\
   \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
   \varepsilon a_{n,1} & \varepsilon a_{n,2} & \cdots & \varepsilon a_{n,n}+ 1  \end{pmatrix}
$$

Now use induction on $n$ to conclude.

Comment: What is the identity that you are using here?

Comment: this is the multilinearity according to lines.