# Show that $\lim\limits_{t \to 0}\frac{Det(A+tB)-Det(A)}{t} = Det(A)\cdot Trace(A^{-1}B)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, determinant, trace

Show that $\lim\limits_{t \to 0}\frac{Det(A+tB)-Det(A)}{t} = Det(A)\cdot Trace(A^{-1}B)$.
Also show that $\langle \nabla Det(A),B \rangle=Det(A)\cdot Trace(A^{-1}B)$.

I know that $det(tI_{n\times n}+C)=t^{n}+Trace(C)t^{n-1}+...+Det(C)$.

This is what I've tried so far:
$$\lim\limits_{t \to 0}\frac{Det(A+tB)-Det(A)}{t} \cdot Det(A^{-1})\cdot Det(A)$$
$$\lim\limits_{t \to 0}\frac{Det(I_{n \times n}+tBA^{-1})-1}{t} \cdot Det(A)$$
Let $C=tBA^{-1}$:
$$\lim\limits_{t \to 0}\frac{Trace(C)\cdot 1^{n-1}+...+Det(C)}{t} \cdot Det(A)$$
But this doesn't seem to be the correct path to the solution.

Comment: I hope you have already solved the problem like in the last step just take common t and then cancel it with denominator, so now all has a t but the first term namely Trace$(A^{-1}B)$ and you are done by putting $t=0$

Comment: Compare: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1258927, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1073278

Comment: Hint: transform your formula for $det(tI_{n\times n}+C)$ into a formula for $det(I_{n\times n}+tC)$, then everything should be clear. Don't "hide" the $t$ variable inside some expressions.

Comment: Thanks I was able to solve the first part. Can someone give me a tip for showing that $⟨∇Det(A),B⟩=Det(A)⋅Trace(A^{-1}B)$?